# Освобождение ввода в консоли ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu

Всем доброго времени суток.
Если запускать приложение c# используя mono на ubuntu,то пока программа не закроется,дальнейший ввод недоступен.
Как можно освободить консоль для ввода не закрывая приложение.

Comment: 1) Вам нужно добавить вначале своего ника  латинскую или русскую букву, иначе то большинство здешнего населения, которое не имеет у себя установленной грузинской раскладки клавиатуры, не сможет отвечать вам в комментариях к другим не вашим вопросам и ответам к ним, т.к. целевые комментарии требуют ввода имени после знака @, например @Bulson.
2) как вам уже ответил @KoVadim в конце команды запуска программы нужно поставить знак `&` или же писать программу, которая не привязана к выводу в консоль, т.е. демона (в терминах Unix) или  процесс (в терминах Windows)

Comment: Не думал что ник может проблемы вызвать,исправил.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Данное решение не зависит от того, запускается через mono или другими трансляторами. Просто добавьте в конец команды `&`. Если терминал покажется "занятым", просто нужно нажать enter.

Comment: Это единственный способ?

Comment: Вот к примеру.Программа на плюсах,без расширения.
Запускается совсем иначе http://clip2net.com/s/3OsNjy2

Comment: Конечно же это не единственный способ. Хорошие программы умеют "отцепляется от терминала", и обычно, эта процедура называется демонизацией.